# Google Charts Multiple Y-Axes (3+ Axes)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find an answer to this.  Essentially, I'm creating a Google Chart that has many (more than 2) Y-Axes.  The Charts allow you to do this, but they bunch the various values for the Y-Axes (see example 1 below).

I utilized another service, HighCharts, and was able to accomplish this quite easily (See example 2 below).  If anybody has some information on how to accomplish this with Google Charts, I'd be infinitely grateful.

Example 1 (Google Charts): http://austincjenkins.com/1.html

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #chart_div {
          background-color: #999;
          border: 3px solid #000;
          border-radius: 20px;
          width: 750px;
          height: 500px;
          padding: 5px;
      }
      .left-margin {
          margin-left: 20px;
      }
     </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Time', 'Rate', 'Ratio1', 'Total', 'Productivity', 'Percent'],
            ['Jan-12',  300,  1000,  1000,  600,  2],
            ['Feb-12',  200,  1200,  2000,  700,  5],
            ['Mar-12',  150,  1300,  3000,  650,  8],
            ['Apr-12',  100,  1400,  4000,  700,  10],
            ['May-12',  85,  1500,  5000,  600,  12],
            ['Jun-12',  90,  1600,  6000,  700,  31],
            ['Jul-12',  60,  1700,  7000,  600,  20],
            ['Aug-12',  45,  1800,  8000,  700,  15],
            ['Sep-12',  65,  1900,  9000,  650,  28],
            ['Oct-12',  35,  2000,  10000,  700,  35],
            ['Nov-12',  40,  2100,  11000,  600,  45],
            ['Dec-12',  31,  2200,  12000,  700,  55],
            ['Jan-13',  28,  2300,  13000,  600,  55],
            ['Feb-13',  22,  2400,  14000,  700,  55],
            ['Mar-13',  18,  2500,  15000,  650,  45],
            ['Apr-13',  15,  2600,  16000,  700,  60],
            ['May-13',  16,  2700,  17000,  600,  60]        
        ]);

         var options = {           
            title: '',  // Here you can give the graph a title and position it         
            chartArea:{ // Here we can customize the size of the positioning and size of the chart
                top: 10,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                width: "75%",
                heigh: "75%"
            },
            fontSize: '', // Enter a number here if you'd like to adjust the font size of ALL the elements in the graph
            //fontName: '', // Enter the name of a font here if you'd like to change the default
            backgroundColor: { // Here we can customize the background of the chart
                fill: "transparent" 
            }, 
            curveType: "function", // can also be "function" to smooth out lines
            hAxis: { // Here we can stylize the X-Axis
                //title: 'Period',  
                slantedText: 'true',
                showTextEvery: 1,
                //titleTextStyle: { // This stylizes the X-axis title ("Period")
                //  color: 'black', 
                    //fontName: '', 
                //  fontSize: 20
                //}
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom",
                alignment: "center",
                background: "#fff"
            },  // Here we can customize and position the 
            // The following allows us to customize the series points.
            series:[
                // "RATE"
                {targetAxisIndex:0, color: "red", pointSize: 8, visibleInLegend: true}, 
                // "Ratio1"
                {targetAxisIndex:1, color: "blue", pointSize: 8, visibleInLegend: true, offset: 20}, 
                // Total
                {targetAxisIndex:2, color: "orange", pointSize: 8, visibleInLegend: true}, 
                // Productivity
                {targetAxisIndex:3, color: "black", pointSize: 8, visibleInLegend: true}, 
                // Percent
                {targetAxisIndex:4, color: "green", pointSize: 8, visibleInLegend: true}
            ],
            vAxes:[  // Here we can customize the Y-Axes
                { // Left axis
                        left: 50,
                    titleTextStyle: { // This stylizes the X-axis title ("Period")
                        color: 'black', 
                        //fontName: '', 
                        fontSize: 20,
                    }
                }, 
                { // Right axis
                    title: "Total",
                    titleTextStyle: { // This stylizes the X-axis title ("Period")
                        color: 'black', 
                        //fontName: '', 
                        fontSize: 20
                    }
                } 
            ]
         };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example 2 (HighCharts): http://austincjenkins.com/2.html

Comment: I don't believe Google charts provide any real support for more than two axis.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. You're probably right. Strange that it would allow you to add more than two targetAxisIndex, though, which is why I wanted to get the the experts opinions!

Comment: As Mark said, this isn't supported by Google currently, and likely for good reason. The second chart with 5 different Y-axes is absolutely useless from a visualization perspective. Since the scales are all arbitrary, and the "size" of the Y-axis for each item will change, comparing the values becomes an exercise in futility. If you were to set them all on the same base (a 0-100 scale, for instance) then they may have meaning, and you could plot them on GViz, but as is it just makes it impossible to tell what you're looking at.

Comment: I have a pretty good use-case for this. Let's say you have N number of events, and M number of metrics measured during each event. I want to display a Column Chart, where I'd group the measurements by metrics, and within each group you could see the measurements for the series of events. I do not want to generate M number of charts, the overhead of all the legends and stuff would be overwhelming. But I also understand that it's not possible to display all of the scales for the M metrics on the Y axis.

Comment: The scenario described by me would allow quick glimpse look at trends of the metrics grouped by metrics. The events have a time line, so it's a trend in time.

Comment: Use case here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes/dark-unica